# python pandas rolling apply on sub datafram and return multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apply, rolling-computation

if I have a dataframe look like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(100), 'b':range(100, 200)})
```

I am trying to operate on a rolling window of `df` and return multiple columns

```
def sub_operate(x, whole_df):
    sub_df = whole_df.loc[x.index]
    // this is the returned row, and row index should be sub_df.index[-1]
    // the last index of the window
    return {'e1':1, 'e2':2, 'e3':3} 


result = df.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: sub_operate(x, df))
```

And I want the returned row be indexed as `sub_df.index[-1]`, which is the last row index value of that part of `df` passed into `sub_operate` function.
Hope someone can kindly enlighten me how to do that?